# Logitech MX Master X CSS page overflow

Tags: css, overflow, logitech, mxmaster3

In our team everybody uses the Logitech MX Master 1-3. There is a browser bug that allows you to scroll out of the page container indefinitely. See attached screenshots. It only happens with Logitech MX Master mouse and just sometimes. Esp. when you want to replicate it, you can't..

Is there a way to prevent it?

https://youtu.be/YF7LmNjYvcw

Comment: does it happen on all websites or any particular website?

Comment: I think it happens on all websites, since I didn't find any link across pages where the issue occures

Comment: Can you share a link to the website? (is it https://uzo.wbz/en?)

Comment: Did someone figure out how to fix this horrible bug?

Comment: Unfortunately no 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few years later, we still didn't find a solution for this bug. Most of the suggested solutions here require some settings in the logitech options etc. but that is not acceptable for us since we want to solve the issue for our visitors and try explaining them to change some settings to fix this bug. Quite unrealistic.

So we are ignoring it since it's only appearing for visitors using the Logitech MX Master, it's not that crucial and you can live with it.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why, but it's happening when mousewell is scrolling in the moment page is loading (MX master2 + google chrome + open dev tool). I think we can't fix it by html,css,js. Reduce the chance to see this bug - set smartShit=disabled. When I get this bug - I reopen page on the new tab.

Comment: Just use your touchpad to scroll and the page will return to normal, no need to reopen the page. ( it is not the solution but it will save some time :D )

Answer (score 2):

having this problem as well and i'm using mx 3 on Google Chrome. do you happen to be using a mac, as i tested on other OS it's working fine.

Anyway, I solve this by updating Logi Options from my Mac.

If for some reason, you prefer to have Logi options around, you can also disable rubberbanding to fix this:

defaults write -g NSScrollViewRubberbanding -bool false

Comment: Disabling rubberbanding fixed it, thanks so much! Should be the accepted answer.

Comment: haha no worries. Actually I solved mine by updating LogiOptions. didn't know they updated the software recently.

Answer (score 1):

disabling smartShift solved my problem
http://joxi.ru/D2P1Y15iwvp8VA

[image]

you need this software to customise the settings
https://www.logitech.com/en-us/software/options.html

Answer (score 0):

What frameworks are you using? I've had this problem with using slick slider inside of a flexbox. Try adding `overflow: hidden` to the `follow_us` row.